# Do VB6 apps run in Azure RemoteApp?

Tags: azure, vb6, windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp

I suppose this is more of a question of whether the VB6 Runtime runs on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I was thinking about Azure app migration scenarios, and Azure RemoteApp could be a great way to allow an enterprise to migrate to the cloud and Windows 10, while still supporting their legacy LOB applications; such as those written in VB6.

I wasn't able to find any information in the Azure documentation specifically on this, so I thought I'd ask it here.

Does anyone know if a VB6 app can run in Azure RemoteApp?

Comment: Dunno about RemoteApp but *VB6 Runtime runs on Windows Server 2012 R2* - Yes it does.

Comment: That's good to know! Thanks!

Comment: basically anything that runs on Windows Server 2012 R2 remotely using remote desktop with support to multi user sessions works on remoteapp. Another pre-requisite is that your application can't save anything locally like a local database because Azure will spawn several VMs for your app and your app needs to work independently where the user connected.

Comment: VB6 Runtime does run on Windows Server although only using Windows-On-Windows (i.e. running as a 32-bit process). See [Microsoft support statement for VB6 runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that perhaps VB6 apps did run in Azure RemoteApp, but this is no longer really relevant, right? **Long live VB6!** :)