# Looking for suggestions for running a VB6 application in the "cloud"

Tags: azure, vb6, cloud

I have a Win32 application written in VB6 that uses an MS Access database as its data file.

I have about 30 clients who use this application.  Each currently has it setup in their local network.  Some clients have a Terminal Server for staff to access their network remotely.

A number of my clients are inquiring about the possibility of using the application in the cloud.

I am considering the possibility of ultimately making the application web based in some form, however that will take many months to do.  So, in the meantime, I am looking for suggestions as to how clients could run this application in the "cloud".

Would it be possible to run it using Microsoft Azure in some way?

I am also wondering whether I could rent a Virtual Private Server myself, and then set it up to allow multiple clients to connect to it (with each using their own individual data file).  My main question around this option is whether there would be additional license costs for users who need to connect (eg. like the old Terminal Services "Client Access Licenses").

One function of the application is that users are able to "attach" electronic files (word documents, pdf's etc) to file notes.  These "attachments" are stored in a subfolder of the data file location (ie they are not stored in the data file).  So the solution *must* be able to support uploading local documents to the "cloud" service.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Many thanks,

Rohan

Comment: May I ask what's the motive behind running your desktop application in the cloud? What benefits are you thinking you may get out of this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Azure but this [Remote App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/remoteapp/) thing sounds like the Azure equivalent of Terminal Server. See [does vb6 runtime work with RemoteApp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705742/do-vb6-apps-run-in-azure-remoteapp)

Comment: @GauravMantri It's not me, it's the clients :-) ... I think their main motivation is cost reduction in so far as getting rid of their in-house servers.

Comment: @user6102577 Do you have any update on how you got on with this?  I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with "Virtual Machine" feature of MS Azure.

1. Acces **portal.azure.com**
2. In the left navigation bar, choose **"Virtual Machine"**
3. Click **"Add"**, type **"windows"** into the search field & press
   **Enter**
4. Choose the Windows VM you want
5. Connect, upload your VB6 app & test it...

Please be inform that some Windows VMs require MSDN subscription or cost very much.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @TriNguyen, I will test this out.

Answer (score 2):

The Azure feature you are looking for is likely **Azure RemoteApp**. It allows for desktop applications to be installed in the Azure "cloud" and then used by users from any device using Remote Desktop Services functionality. This way you can control the environment where the application is installed, and not have to configure every users device; which is especially helpful with older legacy applications like VB6 apps.

https://www.remoteapp.windowsazure.com/en/

EDIT: Unfortunately on [August 12, 2016 Microsoft announced they are discontinuing Azure Remote App](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/08/12/application-remoting-and-the-cloud/). New purchases of RemoteApp will be discontinued October 1, 2016, and the service will be replaced with an offering from Citrix called [Citrix XenApp Express](https://www.citrix.com/global-partners/microsoft/remote-app.html).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @ChrisPietschmann, I will test this.

Comment: Azure RemoteApp has been discontinued https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/08/12/application-remoting-and-the-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simply create a virtual server for each of your clients.  Do not create 1 virtual server for everyone, that will be a nightmare and very insecure for client data.

The clients would still just access over terminal services or Remote Desktop as they have before, just the server is now in the cloud.

Then you can bill each client for the what you are charged for their server.

Answer (score 0):

RUN EXCEL/ACCESS DATABASE ON THE CLOUD WITHOUT PROGRAMMING!

I can solve your problem without using Azure or similar. We would first convert your Excel/Access database to a Progen4GL-based applications, which will then run on the cloud.  See downloads on www.progencloud.com.

If you can, send us a similar Access/Excel file. We will convert it to a Progen4GL database that you can run the on the cloud with full read/write access. As Progen4GL reads in Access/Excel files without programming, we can do it for your for nothing. It takes only a few minutes for the to conversion to a Progen4GL Database. We will return it to you as a Cloud application. See Progen DataOWL on www.progencloud.com and try it yourself. You will need some help from us to run it on the Cloud as the website doesn't have full details.

Ravi Raizada  raviraiz@aol.com
www.progencloud.com